# tableview from multiple core data entities swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, core-data

I am struggling with something I think should be basic but cannot figure out. I have two entities in core data with a one to one and one to many relationship. They are Company which can have multiple Opportunities.I want to load a table view listing the opportunities (sorted by name) with their associated companies. Can this be done by simply accessing the Opportunity entity? If so, how do I access company? The Opportunity class references it as a "Company" type and so I tried to go using dot notation through to company.companyName but it failed on that, and if I change it to simply company (of type Company) it does show .Company: and other reference data but not the simple name field I am looking for. This seems as if it should be simple but...........

Comment: Please show what you tried (and how it failed).

Answer (score 0):

This was simple and I was overlooking the ability to load the fetchedresultscontroller with the right type (in my case the Opportunity class) and then use dot notation from there. I was trying to do it with key value access which did not work. Cheers

Comment: Your answer is as vague as your question. If you want this thread to be of any use for future readers then please show concretely both what you tried and how you solved it.